# Xcode - how to insert code into a specific location

Tags: xcode, include

I have a standard piece of NSUserDefault code that I want to merge into a number of pages at compile time. Unlike Include they need the code inserted into a specific location.

I presume Xcode supports this? e.g.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[INSERT CODE HERE]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the code into a method and call it where appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Define a function or method and call as you would normally. Use search and replace, if needed.

---

Note that you *could* do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
#include "some_file.h"
}
```

…but that's the kind of style i would (personally) reject from my codebases.

ps: A more detailed description could help you get a more exact answer.